# How can I find an element by class and get the value?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the value of an input text field.

the HTML is:

```
<div id="start">
    <p>
        <input type="text" class="myClass" value="my value" name="mytext"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

The jquery is:

```
var myVar = $("#start").find('myClass').val();
```

The problem is that myVar is coming up undefined.  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Class selectors are prefixed with a dot. Your `.find()` is missing that so jQuery thinks you're looking for `<myClass>` elements.

```
var myVar = $("#start").find('.myClass').val();
```

Comment: @Jason: You may want to post the actual code. I have a gut feeling it's not as simple as it looks.

Comment: Your right.  This is a watered down version of the code to simplify it.  It appears the concept should work.

Comment: @Jason can you please post the solution, I have a feeling we are doing the same thing.

Comment: Why the answer is exactly the same query as the one he is mentioning in hsi question as not working?

Comment: @Zaibis: The original code wasn't the same - look at the revision history. Frankly I think the question should be closed since it seems to have been a different problem and we haven't been given much to go on.

Comment: Would be best as he says "This is not working: 'correct working queryy'" -> this Was just confusing me untill I realized that he eddited his question.

Answer (score 20):

```
var myVar = $("#start").find('.myClass').first().val();
```

Answer (score 11):

`var myVar = $("#start").find('myClass').val();`

needs to be

`var myVar = $("#start").find('.myClass').val();`

Remember the CSS selector rules require "." if selecting by class name. The absence of "." is interpreted to mean searching for `<myclass></myclass>`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also get the value by the following way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#start").click(function(){
    alert($(this).find("input[class='myClass']").val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get value of id,name or value in this way.
class name my_class

```
 var id_value = $('.my_class').$(this).attr('id'); //get id value
 var name_value = $('.my_class').$(this).attr('name'); //get name value
 var value = $('.my_class').$(this).attr('value'); //get value any input or tag
```