# Multiple Classes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have multiple classes with different values. The values are generated from MySql. How do I get the value of all the 'VALUEs' i.e 1,2,3,4 in order to post it to my query? Each input has its own button and form. If i click the first button i want it to post 1, then the next button and form will post 2.

```
<input type="hidden" class="hideID" name="id" value="1">
<input type="hidden" class="hideID" name="id" value="2">
<input type="hidden" class="hideID" name="id" value="3">
<input type="hidden" class="hideID" name="id" value="4">
```

My jquery code currently only gets the first value (1):

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(){

var hideID = $('.hideID').val();

alert(hideID);
});
```

Comment: it's normal.... look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287736/jquery-find-class-and-get-the-value

Answer (score 1):

you need a loop for this. `$(".hideID")` is returning an array with all your elements with the class "hideID". so you need something like this to read all values

```
$.each($(".hideID"),function(index,element){
  console.log($(element).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should return all the values of your hidden fields in alert popups but maybe you should give them all different names. `name="id"` might conflict somewhere down the line.

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(){
    $.each($('.hideID'),function(index,element){
      alert($(element).val());
    });
});
```

You can play around with it on [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qmuwt/).

Comment: Hi thanks, actually what i am looking for is when i click it gives me one value since the inputs are on separate forms with separate vales and buttons. Thank you.