# How to get the value of an entity in a class?

Tags: jquery, html

I have HTML like

```
 <div class="test" id="12345"></div>
```

Using jquery, how can I get the value of id with the class name?

Comment: `$('div.test').attr('id')`

Comment: `$(".test").attr("id")` or `$(".test")[0].id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery find class and get the value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287736/jquery-find-class-and-get-the-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
var id = $('div.test').attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks, @Bhushan. Got it.

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
var id=$('.test').attr('id');
```