# JQuery .find() can find by id, but not by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created the following DOM using Jquery:

```
<div id="d0" class="choiceDiv">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cb0" class=".userCheckBox" value="Option 1" checked="checked">
    <input type="hidden" id="h0" class=".userCheckBoxHidden" value="true">
    <label for="cb0">Option 1</label>
</div>
```

I've applied CSS tags to my elements in the DOM, through the CSS classes do not have any properties inside of them at this point.

There are about 17 of these in a div. After the page has been loaded, I'd like to reload the current checked value of each checkbox. As I iterate through each code, I try to use the .find() function on the DOM:

```
$('.choiceDiv').each(function(e){
```

When I try to find by Class,

```
$(this).find('.userCheckBox');
```

I get the following failure Object:

```
init [prevObject: init(1), context: div#d0.choiceDiv, selector: ".userCheckBox"]
context: div#d0.choiceDiv
length: 0
prevObject:init [div#d0.choiceDiv, context: div#d0.choiceDiv]
selector:".userCheckBox"
__proto__:Object(0)
```

When I try to find by ID,

```
$(this).find('#cb'+e)[0];
```

I get what I'm looking for:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb0" class=".userCheckBox" value="Option 1" checked="checked">
```

I was hoping to pull the object by class to ensure I always get the type of input I'm looking for. Can someone explain why I can use .find() with an ID and not by Class in this instance? I tried figuring it out with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287736/jquery-find-class-and-get-the-value) but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: `class=".userCheckBox"`  take the `.` off.  That is used by selectors to denote a class.  It does not go in your actual markup.  Just as you did not put a `#` in your `id=""`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove the period from the class attribute. For example:

`<input type="checkbox" id="cb0" class="userCheckBox" value="Option 1" checked="checked">`

Could be found via `.find('.userCheckBox')` or `.find('#cb0')`.

Comment: Thanks so much, Cameron and Teplar! Wish my eyes weren't so cross-eyed!