# I have a div element that I want to show/hide using a toggle button in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

My HTML div code is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-default" >
        <div class="panel-heading">{t}Add product{/t}
            <button class="btn-toggle">{'Toggle'|t}</button>
        </div>
        <div id = "addProductDiv" class="panel-body" style="display: none;">
            Some random data
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("btn-toggle").click(function(){
            $('#addProductDiv').toggle();
        });
});
```

But it does not hide my div

Comment: `'btn-toggle'` targets `<btn-toggle>` element. You want to target a class, so you need to write `.btn-toggle`.

Comment: You appear to be using Bootstrap. Consider applying Bootstrap's [collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/collapse/) feature rather than writing your own. Also, [you might not need jQuery](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find an element by class and get the value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287736/jquery-find-class-and-get-the-value)

Comment: Kinda, it helps but it hides all the <div> elements I have on the respective page. Any suggestion how can I make it more focused on my particular div?